# Does there exist a search algorithm that takes advantage of the distribution of the searchable values being known?

Tags: algorithm, search, distribution

For instance, I have a list of values 1 through 10. The values are in a sorted array. Since I know the upper bound, and lower bound, median, mean... etc. and that the values are ordered, is there not an algorithm that can take advantage of this knowledge and provide a fast and efficient search for the location of a particular value?

Comment: How about binary search?

Comment: Also in some databases you can "optimize" your tables. when it optimizes, it looks at the distribution of your numbers, what numbers are common etc. If you look for something larger than the maximum it will instantly tell you it couldn't find it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.

This sounds like a pretty good candidate for any form of a divide-and-conquer algorithm with O(logn) complexity (you are halving the problem space on each step).

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Algorithm and implement in your language of choice.

Java (binary search): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html

Python (bisect): http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html

Hope this helps.
Edmon